# How to write session maintainance login in python?

Tags: python, html, session

I am developing a project in python. I wanted to develope a session maintenace code into it. And What i had done was created a session at user login by just taking current time and add a 30 minute into it and store it into databse as a timeout value. after 30 minutes the session get expired. But actully as per my expert knowledge the session login works like. If user does not perform any action for an 10 to 15 minutes session needs to get expired but if user perform any action for an whole hour then session does not need to get expired. But with my login thse session get expired after every 30 minutes irrespective of user performce any action or not. So i just want to change my login. So anyone knows how should i write to convert the my logic so it performce as per our expectations.And what we done is as follows:

Created session at user login by :

```
sessions.new(user=user.id, token=token, timeout=datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(minutes=30))
```

And function for session maintenance is :

```
def add_session(context):
context['session'] = None
context['user'] = None
session_user = bottle.request.get_cookie("user", secret=config.session_secret)
session_token = bottle.request.get_cookie("token", secret=config.session_secret)
if session_user and session_token:
    session = sessions.get(user=session_user, token=session_token)
    if session:
        if session.timeout and session.timeout < datetime.datetime.now():
            context['errors'].append("Your session has timed out.")
            sessions.remove(**session)
            return context
        context['session'] = session
        context['user'] = session.user.typed()
        return context
return context
```

Thanks in advance.